# MobX: @observale won't evoke render

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying to build a view where if an element is clicked the child nodes are displayed. Everything works fine as long as i call `this.forceUpdate();` in my onClick event. What I want to do is have my data as an observable array so that any changes in it would evoke `render()`. However to keep things simple to begin with, I am declaring an `@observable boolean` and toggling the values to evoke render. However upon the value change, `render()` is not called. What am I doing wrong here?

my code:

```
@observer
export class TreeView extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>> {
    @observable toggle = false;
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    public renderChildrenNodes = (e) => {
        const id = e.currentTarget.id;
        if(!id) {
            return;
        }
        let item: INode = this.props.data.find(item => item.Name === id );
        if(item) {
            item.Show = !item.Show;
            this.toggle = !this.toggle;
            // USE MOBX
            // this.forceUpdate();
        }
    }

    public render() {
        const data = this.props.data;
        if (!data) {
            return null;
        }
        return(
            <ul className="no-padding">
                {data.map((item,itr) => {
                    return (
                        <li className="list-style" key={itr}>
                            <div id={item.Name} className="box" onClick={this.renderChildrenNodes}>
                                {item.Name}
                            </div>
                            {item.Show ? <TreeView data={item.ChildNodes} /> : null}
                        </li>
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mobx trigger a re-render only if your `render` function is referencing the *obserbable* somewhere.

Here an old but good article on how to use mobx for component local state: https://blog.cloudboost.io/3-reasons-why-i-stopped-using-react-setstate-ab73fc67a42e